# Sleep until system has spare resources? Low priority task scheduling

Tags: java, multithreading

There's a list of things that my program needs to periodically check - no events can be assigned to trigger when their state changes. These *things* are stored in array list as Robot class instances:

```
public class RobotManager extends Thread {
  protected final List<Robot> robots = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Every robot has `canRun` task which returns true if there's someting the robot can do. This includes updating availability of GUI buttons and so on.

My current plan was to sleep for some while, like 800ms, then loop through list and `canRun` (and eventually `start()`) every `Robot` in the list. But this doesn't seem very nice - if there's sufficient number of tasks, the program will lag the system every 800ms. It would be much nicer if the program could:

1. Tell the OS to `sleep` for *something around* 800ms with less precision and try to run where there are spare resources
2. Do these unprecise `sleep`s while looping the list to reduce the peak in required resources.

In other words: Can I, in Java, make `sleep` less precise in favour of running when system has spare resources?

Comment: take care that if you `run()` instead of `start()`, you executin in the same thread

Comment: Oh, yes. I will edit this, I meant `start`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `Thread.yield()`method.

Javadoc:

```
 A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield
 its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this
 hint.

 Yield is a heuristic attempt to improve relative progression
 between threads that would otherwise over-utilise a CPU. Its use
 should be combined with detailed profiling and benchmarking to
 ensure that it actually has the desired effect.

 It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful
 for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce
 bugs due to race conditions. It may also be useful when designing
 concurrency control constructs such as the ones in the
 java.util.concurrent.locks package.
```

With a combination of `sleep(...)` and `yield()` you can find a tradeoff between "robots list is not processed often enough" and "it's eating up to much cpu". The amount of time you sleep and the number of yield calls (within the robots and/or between robot calls) depends on the stuff your robots actually do.

Comment: The problem is that the `yield` doesn't give me any idea when is the thread going to get the control back. What I wanted is to tell the scheduler not to start the loop along (or even instead of) some critical foreground task.

Comment: Usually you would use a lock that blocks your robots when there is a critical foreground task. When you can not do that, I think the best way is to use multiple yield calls to drop the cpu time you spend with the robots list. But you need to experiment with it to ensure it has the right effect.

Comment: At this moment what I did is `sleep` and then `yield` to ensure the thread doesn't jump on the CPU after sleep ends. But I'm not very sure about this solution honestly.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to set the process/thread priority to Idle or very low priority. A thread/process that has an Idle priority will only be scheduled if no other tasks with higher priority is ready to run. Note that this opens the possibility of starvation if the current machine is actively very busy, the idle thread won't run at all. A low priority thread would still let you get some time slice, only that it'll yield to higher priority threads first. The specific behaviour of thread priority varies depending on the JVM implementation and the OS, but generally a low priority thread will likely be preempted if a higher priority thread becomes ready to run, and it will be less likely to be scheduled if a higher priority thread is ready to run.

Another comment is that I'd recommend to avoid polling for available task, but rather use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead of ArrayList and sleeping. If your thread is waiting for a BlockingQueue, it won't be scheduled until there's something in the queue, so you don't have the unpredictable wake-up checks. It's also nicer to the machine as a blocked thread would allow the CPU to enter low power mode (unlike a constantly waking thread, which keeps the CPU at its toes), this can be important if your program is running on a machine with battery.

Comment: Blocking queue requires external events (eg. received data from sockets) to fill the queue. This wouldn't work with my design - I already said there are no events for the tasks I perform.